# Assign value from one character array into another in java

Tags: java, arrays

I am writing  program to eliminate vowels in a String. What I want to do is check if the value of the character in the string is a Vowel. If it is false I want to store it in another array as follows:

```
if(isVowel(char_str[i]) == false) {
    temp[index] = char_str[i];
    index = index + 1;
}
```

I get an array out of Bounds exception for the 2nd line. I have initialised both the arrays as follows:

```
String str="Education";
char char_str[]=str.toCharArray();
char temp[] = {};
```

Can someone explain exactly what I am doing that is causing the error. I am a bit out of touch with the working of arrays in Java.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot add an element to an array like this without specifying the array length. You can use `ArrayList` instead to add new elements without specifying the length. So either initialize the array length like this -

```
char temp[] = new char[100]; // Assuming 100 is the highest length
```

or declare an `ArrayList` like this -

```
List<Character> temp = new ArrayList<Character>();
```

You can add a new element to an ArrayList by using the `add` method.

```
temp.add(char_str[i]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You are attempting to access an element of an empty array.

This line

```
char temp[] = {};
```

Creates an empty array - one with no elements.

So this

```
temp[index] = ...
```

Will explode because there are no positions to assign a value to.

Allocate some space, eg:

```
char temp[] = new char[str.length()];
```

Comment: @Kira_99 read the last line of my answer.

Comment: I am still encountering the same error, even when I allocate space to the array.